# Java Exception in thread EOFException

Tags: java, database, exception, eofexception

I'm working on a data struct project and can't seem to find out why I am getting this exception. When I run my project in eclipse this is the error it gives.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:803)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLong(RandomAccessFile.java:836)
    at project_test.BTree.<init>(myClassB.java:75)
    at project_test.URLTestBNode.main(myClassA.java:25)
```

Does it simply mean that it cannot locate the URL I gave it?

Looking at relevant code around lines 25:

```
public class myClassA {
20) public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    21) URL url1 = new URL("The first URL");
    22) URL url2 = new URL("The second URL");
    23) RandomAccessFile rf1 = new RandomAccessFile(url1.toString().replace("/",""),"rw");
    24) RandomAccessFile rf2 = new RandomAccessFile(url2.toString().replace("/",""),"rw");
    25) BTree tree1 = new BTree(rf1, 64); //Error this line
    26) BTree tree2 = new BTree(rf2, 64);
    ...
    }
}
```

Relevent code around line 75:

```
public class myClassB{
69) public myClassB(RandomAccessFile f, int k) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{

    71) file = f;
    72) file.seek(0);

    73) byte[] url = new byte[256];
    74) file.read(url);

    75) long rootIndex = file.readLong(); //This line
    76) file.seek(rootIndex);
    ...
    }
}
```

The only thing I can really think of is if it can't find the stored URL for some reason or if it's not registering that I added the exception in there. Any ideas on what I can do to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

EOF means End Of File. Your program tries to read beyond the end of the file. This means either that the file is truncated, too short, corrupted or that you have a bug in the `BTree` read or write code.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you achieve the end of file and you  try to read more.